# IF-block syntax

Tags: if-statement, fortran

I'm trying to compare a month array to check whether each number is a odd month or even month so that I can make files labelled as the month//date//year.txt and upload lines matching the date from another files into the respective .txt file.

My output should be 90 .txt files, each containing the lines matching the particular date from APM_FORMATTED.txt.

```
PROGRAM APM_TEST
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: READSTATUS, YEAR_MIN, MONTH_MIN, DAY_MIN, YEAR_MAX, MONTH_MAX, DAY_MAX, I, IND, IND1, D, D1, D2 
CHARACTER(13) :: DATE_INPUT
CHARACTER(2) :: FILE_DAY, FILE_MONTH, FILE_YEAR, CURRENT_DAY, CURRENT_MONTH
CHARACTER(632) :: ROW1
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,6) :: M
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,6) :: N
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,3) :: MON


WRITE(*,'(" ENTER DATE RANGE OF FILE (E.G. 010413-010713):")', ADVANCE = "NO")
        READINT : DO
            READ (*,*,IOSTAT=READSTATUS) DATE_INPUT
            IF (READSTATUS==0) THEN
            EXIT READINT
            ELSE
            WRITE(*,'(/"READ ERROR. PLEASE RE-INPUT:")')
            ENDIF
        ENDDO READINT

        READ(DATE_INPUT(5:6), '(I2)') YEAR_MIN 
        READ(DATE_INPUT(3:4), '(I2)') MONTH_MIN
        READ(DATE_INPUT(1:2), '(I2)') DAY_MIN
        READ(DATE_INPUT(12:13), '(I2)') YEAR_MAX
        READ(DATE_INPUT(10:11), '(I2)') MONTH_MAX
        READ(DATE_INPUT(8:9), '(I2)') DAY_MAX




        IND=1
        IND1=1
        M=(/1,3,5,7,9,11/)
        N=(/4,6,8,10,12/)

36      DO MON=MONTH_MIN, MONTH_MAX
            IF (ANY(M.EQ.MON(IND))) THEN

                DO D=DAY_MIN,31
                    FILE_DAY=DATE_INPUT(1:2)
                    FILE_MONTH=DATE_INPUT(3:4)
                    FILE_YEAR=DATE_INPUT(5:6)
                    OPEN(UNIT=201, FILE="APM_FORMATTED.TXT")
                    OPEN(IND1, FILE=(FILE_MONTH//FILE_DAY//FILE_YEAR//".TXT"), ACTION="WRITE", STATUS="NEW") 
45                  DO I=1,200000
                        READ(201,'(A632)') ROW1
                        IF (ROW1(1:3).EQ.'APM') THEN
                        READ(ROW1(41:42), '(I2)') CURRENT_DAY
                        READ(ROW1(43:44), '(I2)') CURRENT_MONTH

                            IF (CURRENT_MONTH.EQ.MON .AND. CURRENT_DAY.EQ.D) THEN 
                            WRITE(IND1,*) ROW1
                            ELSE
                            GOTO 45
                            ENDIF

                        ELSE 
                        ENDIF
                    ENDDO
                    IND1=IND1+1
                    CLOSE(IND1)
                    CLOSE(201)
                ENDDO

            ELSEIF (ANY(N.EQ.MON)) THEN

                DO D1=DAY_MIN,30
                    FILE_DAY=DATE_INPUT(1:2)
                    FILE_MONTH=DATE_INPUT(3:4)
                    FILE_YEAR=DATE_INPUT(5:6)
                    OPEN(UNIT=201, FILE="APM_FORMATTED.TXT")
                    OPEN(IND1, FILE=(FILE_MONTH//FILE_DAY//FILE_YEAR//".TXT"), ACTION="WRITE", STATUS="NEW") 
73                  DO I=1,200000
                        READ(201,'(A632)') ROW1
                        IF (ROW1(1:3).EQ.'APM') THEN
                        READ(ROW1(41:42), '(I2)') CURRENT_DAY
                        READ(ROW1(43:44), '(I2)') CURRENT_MONTH

                            IF (CURRENT_MONTH.EQ.MON .AND. CURRENT_DAY.EQ.D1) THEN 
                            WRITE(IND1,*) ROW1
                            ELSE
                            GOTO 73
                            ENDIF

                        ELSE
                        ENDIF
                    ENDDO
                    IND1=IND1+1
                    CLOSE(IND1)
                    CLOSE(201)
                ENDDO

            ELSEIF (ANY(M.EQ.4)) THEN 

                DO D2=DAY_MIN,28
                    FILE_DAY=DATE_INPUT(1:2)
                    FILE_MONTH=DATE_INPUT(3:4)
                    FILE_YEAR=DATE_INPUT(5:6)
                    OPEN(UNIT=201, FILE="APM_FORMATTED.TXT")
                    OPEN(IND1, FILE=(FILE_MONTH//FILE_DAY//FILE_YEAR//".TXT"), ACTION="WRITE", STATUS="NEW") 
101                 DO I=1,200000
                        READ(201,'(A632)') ROW1
                        IF (ROW1(1:3).EQ.'APM') THEN
                        READ(ROW1(41:42), '(I2)') CURRENT_DAY
                        READ(ROW1(43:44), '(I2)') CURRENT_MONTH

                            IF (CURRENT_MONTH.EQ.MON .AND. CURRENT_DAY.EQ.D2) THEN
                            WRITE(IND1,*) ROW1
                            ELSE
                            GOTO 101
                            ENDIF

                        ELSE
                        ENDIF

                    ENDDO
                    IND1=IND1+1
                    CLOSE(IND1)
                    CLOSE(201)
                ENDDO
            ELSE 
            GOTO 36
            ENDIF
            IND=IND+1
            DAY_MIN=1

    ENDDO

END PROGRAM APM_TEST

Errors:
error FOR2614: assignment between arrays of differing rank
error FOR2614: assignment between arrays of differing rank
error FOR2799: DO control variable MON is not scalar
error FOR2979: expected 2 subscripts but found 1 for array MON
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3048: illegal data type to binary logical operator .AND. 
error FOR3156: array shapes differ in dimension 2 (extent 6 and 3)
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3048: illegal data type to binary logical operator .AND. 
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3041: operands to relational operator .EQ. are of incompatible data type
error FOR3048: illegal data type to binary logical operator .AND.
```

Comment: INTEGER, DIMENSION(:) :: K   K=(MONTH_MIN,MONTH_MAX)   M=(/ 1,3,5,7,9,11 /)    IND=1    IF (K(IND).EQ.M) THEN    I don't understand why the array is not able to compare with a single integer.

Comment: A scalar is able to compare with the array, but the expression in the `IF` block condition needs to be scalar. If you want to check whether a scalar integer is equal to all or some of the elements, look into intrinsic functions `ALL` and `ANY`.

Comment: I still can't be able to seem to compare arrays using the ANY function: IF (ANY(M).EQ.MON(IND)), where M is the array I'm comparing to and MON(IND) is the different values of the month array. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the usage of `ANY` and `ALL`? It takes an array of the `LOGICAL` kind as argument, and returns a `LOGICAL` scalar. So in your case, `ANY(M == MON(IND))` would return a `LOGICAL` scalar. But I didn't read your code so I don't know whether that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks but when I use IF (ANY(M.EQ.MON(IND)) THEN, it gives me a compile error "assignment between arrays of differing rank". Essentially, I'm writing a program to take in an array of months and compare it with 2 different arrays to determine whether they have 30 days or 31 days. Any more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: At this point, you should update your question with the exact code that is not working, the exact error message, and what result do you expect.

Comment: What swinish compiler are you using that doesn't report line numbers against the errors it finds ?!  Whatever it is get rid of it.  Oh, and save yourself a lot of future pain, write dates in file names as YYMMDD, even DDMMYY if you must, but never never never as MMDDYY.

Comment: Ideally, follow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 as closely as possible.

Comment: Looks like you are using an array as a `DO`-loop counter on line 36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors on lines 38 and 45 (and very likely other lines as well). Look into your favorite book or online tutorial about correct `IF` block and statement syntax. The basic `IF`-block syntax in Fortran is in the form:

```
IF(scalar-logical-expr)THEN
  ...
ELSEIF(scalar-logical-expr)THEN
  ...
ELSE
  ...
ENDIF
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the majority of the synatx errors but I'm having problems with array comparison.